# how to hide an image uploaded by a user from another user in php?

Tags: php

I am working on a **website which sells spectacles** and website provides the **try on feature** to users so that user can try the spec on his image.

Now when a user upload an image he try specs on his photo but if any other user upload his photo he also finds the uploaded image by the other user and if the second user upload his photo then the image which was uploaded by the first user deleted.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Show us your code. But it's a fair bet that you're uploading your images to the same file in your server, you'd need unique names for each upload or at least by user, to avoid your problem.

Comment: Simply just generate unique image name for each image uploaded - therefore You will not overwrite the previous images that had the same name...Store that new random name somewhere in the database so You could always present the right image for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a unique random name (using e.g. `uniqid()`) for each uploaded file and tie it to the user session id or shop account. This way, users always see their picture (you can show him his picture next time he visits - if he has an account).